# if DateExpected is not null then check one condition else check for another condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
(CASE WHEN (NULLIF(DateExpected, '1/1/1900') IS NOT NULL) 
      THEN (DATEDIFF(D, DateExpected, GETDATE()) > 8) 
 ELSE (DATEDIFF(D, ApptDate, GETDATE()) > 27) END)
```

I am applying the logic in where condition of the query. I am getting syntax errors. Please help me.

Comment: what do you expect to return with your case expression?

Comment: And what are your errors??

Comment: When you're getting a syntax error it's probably a good idea to include the entire statement if you hope for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: use `WHERE DATEDIFF(D, NULLIF(DateExpected, '1/1/1900'), GETDATE()) > 8 OR    DATEDIFF(D, ApptDate, GETDATE()) > 27` instead of a `case` in `where`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use CASE in where clause
Try this

```
Where (IsNUll(DateExpected,'1/1/1900') <> '1/1/1900' and DATEDIFF(D, DateExpected, GETDATE()) > 8) or DATEDIFF(D, ApptDate, GETDATE()) > 27
```